# how to compare variables of one class object with another class's object?

Tags: c++, oop

Say I have two classes: player and item
the player has several class variables, including

`int strengthPoints, dexterityPoints, constitutionPoints, intelligencePoints, wisdomPoints, charismaPoints;`

and the item has a variables

`int requiredStrengthPoints, requiredDexterityPoints, requiredConstitutionPoints, requiredIntelligencePoints, requiredWisdomPoints, requiredCharismaPoints;` and
`bool usable;` which checks if the players stats are <= the item's requirements.

The above is very specifc, but the actual, and widely applicable question is this; how does one go about comparing variables of one class object with another class's object? I want to apply this to change the `canUse` variable if the player stats are greater than or equal to the requirements, but I don't know how to compare the two.

the function I currently have looks like so:

```
void item::canEquip(player& playerObject) {

}
```

I'm not sure this is correct, as I can't refer to the player object's variables/functions when I declare the function like this.

Comment: A method that is named `canXXX` should return a `bool` variable.

Comment: Which error do you get when you access `player.strengthPoints`?

Comment: You can make `item` a `friend` of `player` or you can implement get methods for all the variables and then read the private members via getters.

Comment: Why do you need to store whether an item is usable? (And why does the item have a say in the matter? I would expect either `bool player::canEquip(const item& i)` or `bool GameLogic::canEquip(const player& p, const item& i)`.)

Comment: I feel like it makes more sense to have the requirement be stored on the item, that way the variables kept track of on the player itself are specific. Instead of 100 separate canEquip's on the player for each and every item. Maybe that's not what you're saying, but that's what I'm assuming the other method would be in such a case. @molbdnilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encapsulate those values into a `Stats` struct like

```
struct Stats
{
    int strength;
    int dexterity;
    int constitution;
    int intelligence;
    int wisdom;
    int charisma;
};
```

then your `Player` can have a `Stats` indicating their current levels, and the `Item` can have a `Stats` indicating required minimum

```
struct Player
{
    Stats stats;
    // name, etc
};

struct Item
{
    Stats required_stats;
    // name, etc
};
```

then your `can_equip` just compares the `player.stats` to the `item.required_stats`

```
bool can_equip(Player const& player, Item const& item)
{
    return player.stats.strength >= item.required_stats.strength &&
           player.stats.dexterity >= item.required_stats.dexterity &&
           player.stats.constitution >= item.required_stats.constitution &&
           player.stats.intelligence >= item.required_stats.intelligence &&
           player.stats.wisdom >= item.required_stats.wisdom &&
           player.stats.charisma >= item.required_stats.charisma;
}
```

you could also consider overloading `operator<` for the `Stats` struct if that would be more convenient.

Comment: This seems like a much more effective option that loose variables. I forgot about struct to be honest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to give object A access to object B's data members:

- Make object B's data members public instead of private.
- Write getters for object B's data members.
- Make object B a [friend class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of object A.

Some additional remarks:

```
void item::canEquip(player& playerObject) {
```

Shouldn't the return type be `bool`? Shouldn't `playerObject` be `const`? Shouldn't "can equip" be something the player can do, instead of the item? Perhaps "canBeEquipped" is a more suitable name.

Comment: "Shouldn't playerObject be const?"
100%, yes, good call
"Shouldn't "can equip" be something the player can do, instead of the item? Perhaps "canBeEquipped" is a more suitable name."
This is a valid semantic point, I've changed the name of the function for clarity's sake.
"Shouldn't the return type be bool?"
I more wanted this function to be a setter, which would set the bool value given specific conditions, my naming conventions were a bit odd, I'll admit.

Answer (score 0):

All the  attributes:

`attributes(strengthPoints, dexterityPoints, constitutionPoints, intelligencePoints, wisdomPoints, charismaPoints)`

can be encapsulated in a class or struct (named **Stats**), and make it (**Stats**) data member of both **Player** and **Item** class.

The **Stats** class can have comparator operator overload function or a separate function which compares. In the function

```
void item::canEquip(player& playerObject)
```

you can call the comparator method.